# Display jquery ui date value in separate elements

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

I need to show the selected date value in different  'divs', 'spans', or 'p' elements like my example in the link below:

```
<button id="buttonHere">datepicker</button>

<div id="datepicker"></div>

<div id="resultdate">00/00/00</div>

<div id="resultdate_expectation">
  <span>Aug</span>
  <span>31</span>
  <span>2018</span>

</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/alonsoct/qphza/464/

How can I show the date value separately?

Thanks

Comment: This is a handy example: http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#date-formats

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the parts of the date from the datepicker's date attribute in the onSelect function:

```
$("#datepicker").hide();
$("#buttonHere").click(function() {
  $("#datepicker").toggle();
});
$("#datepicker").datepicker({
  onSelect: function(value, date) {
    const months = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June",
      "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"
    ];
    $('#resultdate_expectation span:eq(0)').html(months[date.selectedMonth]);
    $('#resultdate_expectation span:eq(1)').html(date.selectedDay);
    $('#resultdate_expectation span:eq(2)').html(date.selectedYear);
    $("#datepicker").hide();
  }
});
```

**[jsFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/j08691/rty21egz/)**

Comment: Thank you! That's just what I need.

Answer (score 1):

All you need is to set the `dateFormat` option properly:

```
dateFormat: "M d yy",
```

> M - month name short
>
> d - day of month (no leading zero)
>
> yy - year (four digit)

See more: http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#utility-formatDate

Based on your example, you did not specify if you wanted leading zero or not. I assumed not.

https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/qphza/481/

```
$(function() {
  // Set up datepicker toggle functionality

  $("#datepicker").hide();

  $("#buttonHere").click(function() {
    $("#datepicker").toggle();
  });

  $("#datepicker").datepicker({
    dateFormat: "M d yy",
    onSelect: function(value, date) {
      $('#resultdate').html(value);
      $("#datepicker").hide();
    }
  });
});
```

Working as requested. Hope that helps.